# Flutter: How can I covert Android app to iOS app using Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I built an Android app using Flutter and need to build an iOS app as well. Can I just use the same code for the iOS app or is there another way that coverts Android to iOS using Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the same code. Follow the link to build an iOS app.
[flutter build iOS app](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios)

Answer (score 0):

You need a Mac OS to run in iOS device. Just start the simulator and run from vscode or android studio or any other editor you are using. Or just right click on iOS folder and open in xcode and select a device and press run.

You don't need to change code but you can define different style for different platform if you want.